# Predicting values with relation value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I've written a small script which analyzes a .csv file and converts the price column and square feet column into 2 lists.

I want to find a way to get a single value that relates the two lists. I need the value to be able to predict future prices for a sqft amount. Is there a way to do this. I've heard of linreg but i dont know how to use it. Also, in my code I obtain a value but it's two values, what am I doing wrong? How do I do this?

```
filename = 'C:/Users/saeed/Downloads/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv'

df = pandas.read_csv(filename)

print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

with open(filename) as i:
    sqft = [int(row["sq__ft"]) for row in DictReader(i)]


with open(filename) as i:
    price = [int(row["price"]) for row in DictReader(i)]

df[df['sq__ft'] != 0]

print(sqft)
print(price)

from scipy import stats
corr = stats.pearsonr(sqft, price)

print(corr)

z = np.arctanh(corr[0])

print(z)

sigma = (1/((len(df.index)-3)**0.5))

print(sigma)

cint = z + np.array([-1, 1]) * sigma * stats.norm.ppf((1+0.95)/2)

fnl=np.tanh(cint)
print(fnl)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in learning Linear Regression, there are many wonderful sources. Here is a simple blog post where I learnt it from: https://medium.com/@gr33ndata/learn-regressions-analysis-23b789bf2c36

Comment: please summarize links in your answer in case they go stale